# Цикл, присваивающий значения элементам массива с проверкой корректности TryParse

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка. Пытаюсь в консольном приложении создать цикл, который будет присваивать значения элементам массива до тех пор, пока вводимые значения соответствуют формату double.

```
            double[] elements;
            int number = 1;
            for (int i = 0; number > 0; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Введите значение для {number}-го элемента");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                double nmb;
                if (Double.TryParse(input, out nmb))
                {
                    elements[i] = nmb;
                    number++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            Console.Read();
```

Пишет, что используемой локальной переменной elements не присвоено значение. А разве elements[i] = nmb; не является присваиванием?

Comment: вот тут `elements[i] = nmb;` вы присваеваете значение конкретному элементу массива. Точнее пытаетесь присвоить, так как самого массива у вас нет, ведь вы его не создали. Чтобы создать массив, надо `double[] elements = new double[нужное вам количество элементов];`. Если вы заранее не знаете нужное вам количество элементов, то вам лучше использовать список `List<double>` вместо массива.

Comment: Спасибо! Со списком работает как и задумывалось!